# Migration/ Import MediaWiki 1.20.8 to Confluence 5.9.4

Tags: import, migration, mediawiki, confluence

we want to import our MediaWiki into Confluence.
In my research I only find the UWC(=Universal Wiki Converter), which is no longer supportet by Atlassian.

Is there any way of an easy migration?
Another tool, another application or can I still use the UWC, even it isn't supported?

Answer (score 0):

You are right UWC is no longer supported for latest versions. You can export your content from media wiki and then use [Confluence REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api) to restore. However, it's totally depends on the contents that you have in media wiki and options you have on exporting them.